# Reading the post body directly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using Google's re-captcha v2 and Google's Javascript at run time generates a form parameter, with the key `g-recaptcha-response`, dynamically. The markup is this:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcXjGYUAAAAA...g1UKiZ"></div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

You will notice that there is no `<input>` element with name `g-recaptcha-response` as it is generated by the Javascript dynamically.  (Note: the above won't work for you as-is as the page url must match what has been configured at Google using `data-sitekey`.)

Upon clicking Submit, the request body is like this:

```
g-recaptcha-response=03AEMEkE....nLXmlhwEE&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8Oe....93pb
```

I don't know how to use a model for such a scenario. So I am trying to read the request body directly using the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    String result;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body)) {
        result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("/test");
    }
}
```

The `result` is always an empty string, even though I can see that there is data from inspecting the Http stream. Are there any errors in the above code? It compiles and runs without error.

Or is there a built-in class or method that can return the post data in, say, Json?

Comment: May you share the javascript that you are using? I would suggest you put a breakpoint in the action and inspect to Request property "searching" for the "g-recaptcha-response" that should have been sent. And maybe you can customize the input name generated by the js. Regards.

Comment: I have added the markup. I had a breakpoint, but `Request.Body` is a `Stream` object and I don't know how to see its content. `Request.Form.Keys` shows that `g-recaptcha-response` is one of the keys submitted so the data is certainly there.

Comment: Have a look at this article and see if it sheds any light https://github.com/PaulMiami/reCAPTCHA/issues/22#issuecomment-347201708

Comment: The library itself looks interesting and could probably save you some hassle.

Comment: The link is talking about the second half of the task, verifying with Google after getting the form data. But from the sample code, the answer is as simple as `Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"]`!  Thanks.

Comment: @OldGeezer that is correct. Glad you found your answer. The answer provided below is another alternative if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...is there a built-in class or method that can return the post data in, say, Json?

Your example is posting form url encoded data. The built-in [`[FromForm]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromformattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) attribute can bind that to a `Dictionary<string, string>` model. Newtonsoft can convert that model to JSON for server side use, and a `JsonResult` can convert that model to JSON for client-side use.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromForm] Dictionary<string,string> model)
{
    // convert to JSON
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
        .SerializeObject(model, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(json);

    // return JSON
    return new JsonResult(model);
}
```

If we receive a post like this...

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/values HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:5000
Content-Length: 85
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

g-recaptcha-response=03AEMEkE....nLXmlhwEE&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8Oe....93pb
```

...we will then see the following console output.

```
{                                                   
  "g-recaptcha-response": "03AEMEkE....nLXmlhwEE",  
  "__RequestVerificationToken": "CfDJ8Oe....93pb"   
}
```

Comment: @OldGeezer I see new that the POST is using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. As a result, we need the `FromForm` attribute.

Comment: Check the article I linked to in the comments and you'll see a very interesting walk through for razor pages using recaptcha. Good read.